Scaling transformation confusion
I'm reading the yellow book (CFT by Di Francesco) and I came across a bit of a confusing statement.
Consider a scaling transformation $x^\mu \rightarrow x'^\mu = \lambda x^\mu$. Then the metric components transform as $g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = \frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{\lambda^2}$ and hence $x'_\mu = \frac{x_\mu}{\lambda}$. Now in (4.50) the author claims that by rotations and translations we can constrain the 2point function $$\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle = f(|x_1-x_2|).$$ Since it must hold that $$\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle = \lambda^{2\Delta}\langle \phi(\lambda x_1) \phi(\lambda x_2) \rangle,$$ we must have that $$f(x) = \lambda^{2\Delta}f(\lambda x).$$ However, since we fixed $f$ to only depend on the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$, it should be invariant under a scaling, since $$x^2  = x^\mu x_\mu \rightarrow x'^\mu x'_\mu = \lambda x^\mu \frac{x_\mu}{\lambda} = x^2.$$
What am I misunderstanding here?
EDIT: I think my question boils down to the following: If $x'^\mu =\lambda x^\mu$ and $g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = \frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{\lambda^2}$, then how does $x_\mu$ transform here? This is not discussed in the linked question.

This question is similar to: Why do scalars scale?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think this question is a bit more subtle, because I'm not really concerned with the transformation of the fields, but more so with the correlation function and the transformation of the function $f(x)$ in terms of $x^\mu$.

It is not more subtle than the difference between an active and a passive transformation... $f$ should not be invariant.

@ConnorBehan I understand with what's written in the linked question, but I don't understand how $x_\mu$ should transform then. Could you maybe give some details?

It's easy to notice which transformation of $x^2$ will give the right answer. The linked question is about why making $x_\mu$ pick up $\lambda$ and $x^\mu$ pick up $1/\lambda$ is wrong.
